# Invalid ROM Contents - new install

Tags: boot, drivers, system-installation, radeon, windows-vista

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 from a CD over Windows Vista. I recently had a GPU failure on this machine, and while I was experiencing those problems (that made the computer unusable) I successfully booted Ubuntu from the live disc. I have bought and installed an AMD Radeon R7 370 and this has made my machine operable again but I would like to upgrade from Vista anyway.

When I attempt to either Install Ubuntu or simply boot from disc from the live disc menu, I get a blank screen that flashes a message saying "Invalid ROM contents" and then cuts to black, before sometimes restarting the computer in Vista.

I have searched around and it seems the full message (though I cannot see it on my screen) is "radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents". I cannot find a solution to this problem - most answers seem to suggest it isn't fatal. I cannot seem to get past it though.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried making a new LiveCD or even a LiveUSB?

Comment: I have, same result except now a line saying `[.. something off screen...]ailed` appears before the invalid ROM contents, and then the screen goes blank with the left 7/8ths in Ubuntu mauve and the last 1/8th black. I'm assuming my screen is misaligned somehow but pressing enter and escape doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: If your monitor has an auto adjust function I'd use that and wait.